# Using Phoenix with Cloudera Hbase (installed from repo)

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, apache-phoenix

I can get Phoenix working on a standalone **Apache Hbase**

(note, all this is for Hbase 1.0.0 on RHEL6.5)

For the Cloudera flavour of Hbase however I never get it working without it throwing Exceptions. (even tried RHEL7 minimal as en OS)

The same thing happens with Phoenix 4.4 for Hbase 1.0.

```
hbase(main):001:0> version
1.0.0-cdh5.4.4, rUnknown, Mon Jul  6 16:59:55 PDT 2015
```

stack trace:

```
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-60-109 phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-bin]$ bin/sqlline.py localhost:2181:/hbase
Setting property: [isolation, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED]
issuing: !connect jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase none none org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
Connecting to jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase
15/08/06 03:10:25 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/08/06 03:10:26 WARN impl.MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-phoenix.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
15/08/06 03:10:27 WARN ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel: Call failed on IOException
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setRaw(Z)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan;
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1269)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:11619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:7054)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2035)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setRaw(Z)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan;
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.buildDeletedTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:966)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.loadTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1042)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1216)
    ... 10 more

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:56)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService$Stub.createTable(MetaDataProtos.java:11799)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$6.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1273)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$6.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$16.call(HTable.java:1737)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setRaw(Z)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan;
    at ...
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cloudera doesn't officially support Apache phoenix, it's still in cloudera Labs, so you cannot find any Cloudera Pheonix tar.gz files in cloudera repository, The only place where you can find Phoenix in Cloudera repository is in the parcel [repository](http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cloudera-labs/phoenix/parcels/latest/), However parcel can be used only if you install through cloudera manager, latest available version of cloudera Phoenix is 4.3.0.

If you wanted to execute Phoenix 4.4 or 4.5 version on Cloudera Hadoop distribution, you need to re-build phoenix libraries using CDH dependency jars. You cannot simply use apache Phoenix tar.gz

Here is the steps.

*Recently I found that Andrew Purtell has done a tremendous work to make Phoenix compatible with CDH version. The same is available in the below link github page. Download the appropriate branch from the below github link. This saves your time.*

https://github.com/chiastic-security/phoenix-for-cloudera/branches

- Download Apache phoenix 4.5 source from Apache [repository](http://www.motorlogy.com/apache/phoenix/phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0/src/phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-src.tar.gz). (Skip this step if you are downloading from the above github page)

Rebuild the source code using CDH dependency jars - Update pom.xml and 2 source files as follows(My CDH version is 5.4.2)

```
[h4ck3r@host1 phoenix]$ diff phoenix-4.5_Updated/phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-src/pom.xml  phoenix-4.5_Orig/phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-src/pom.xml
28c28
< <!--    <module>phoenix-pig</module> -->
---
>     <module>phoenix-pig</module>
37a38,41
>       <id>apache release</id>
>       <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
>     </repository>
>     <repository>
42,43c46,50
<       <id>cloudera</id>
<       <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos</url>
---
>       <id>apache snapshot</id>
>       <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
>       <snapshots>
>         <enabled>true</enabled>
>       </snapshots>
45d51
<
54d59
<
77,81c82,83
<     <hbase.version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</hbase.version>
<     <hadoop-two.version>2.6.0-cdh5.4.2</hadoop-two.version>
/<     <hadoop.version>2.6.0-cdh5.4.2</hadoop.version>
<     <pig.version>0.12.0</pig.version>
<     <flume.version>1.5.0-cdh5.4.2</flume.version>
---
>     <hbase.version>1.0.1</hbase.version>
>     <hadoop-two.version>2.5.1</hadoop-two.version>
84a87,88
>     <hadoop.version>2.5.1</hadoop.version>
>     <pig.version>0.13.0</pig.version>
97a102
>     <flume.version>1.4.0</flume.version>
449,450c454
<
<   <dependency>
---
>       <dependency>
454c458
<       </dependency>
---
>       </dependency>

[h4ck3r@host1 phoenix]$ diff phoenix-4.5_Updated/phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-src/phoenix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/LocalIndexMerger.java  phoenix-4.5_Orig/phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-src/phoenix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/LocalIndexMerger.java
84c84
<                     rss.getServerName(), metaEntries,1);
---
>                     rss.getServerName(), metaEntries);

[h4ck3r@host1 phoenix]$ diff phoenix-4.5_Updated/phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-src/phoenix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/IndexSplitTransaction.java phoenix-4.5_Orig/phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-src/phoenix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/IndexSplitTransaction.java
291c291
<                 daughterRegions.getSecond().getRegionInfo(), server.getServerName(),1);
---
>                 daughterRegions.getSecond().getRegionInfo(), server.getServerName());
978c978
< }
---
> }
\ No newline at end of file
```

- Above build will create new Jars under target directory of each sub component.
- Download Apache phoenix 4.5 binary from Apache [repository](http://www.motorlogy.com/apache/phoenix/phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0/bin/phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-bin.tar.gz)
- Extract phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-bin.tar.gz and replace the below Phoenix Jars with new Jars

  - phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-client.jar
  - phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-server-without-antlr.jar
  - phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-client-minimal.jar
  - phoenix-assembly-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-tests.jar
  - phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-client-without-hbase.jar
  - phoenix-core-4.5.0-HBase-1.0.jar
  - phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-server.jar
- Replace `phoenix-4.5.0-HBase-1.0-server.jar` and `phoenix-core-4.5.0-HBase-1.0.jar`  in hbase lib location and restart hbase. (In 4.7 only phoenix-4.7.0-cdh5.X.1-server.jar to be copied to hbase lib)
- Execute phoenix command from the new updated directory.

Due to some dependency issues phoenix-pig is not handled, this is just a  workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. In my case, I just unzip the .parcel file and placed the required phoenix libraries at hbase regionservers. This resolved my issue.

Comment: This steps is for phoenix 4.5 release. The reason I posted this steps is that Cloudera yet to release Phoenix 4.5 parcel, The latest available Cloudera parcel version at this moment is 4.3 (http://archive.cloudera.com/cloudera-labs/phoenix/parcels/latest/). If you have installed using parcel, then your phoenix version would be 4.3.

Comment: I am getting the same exception on squirrel client with phoenix 4.6.0 and Hbase 1.0. I copied the server and core jars to the hbase region and master servers but I still get the exception on the client. What could be a resolution? Is there something on the client that is causing this exception? Btw the installation instructions on the phoenix site mention about just a couple of jars. What are these additional jars for (client-minimal, client-without-hbase etc? Thanks !

Comment: @h4ck3r - I tried the above steps for phoenix 4.7-hbase-1.0.rc3 but I still get the exception in my squirrel client. Any suggestions?

Comment: @h4ck3r - I tried the above code changes with phoenix 4.5.0-HBase-1.0 code base but the source doesn't compile. My cloudera version is 5.5.0. Would there be more changes based on the cloudera version?

Comment: @ Andy, Cloudera release Phoenix-5.4.2 version, so you don't have to compile the apache libraries, Just install Phoenix-4.5.0 using parcel, Parcel is available in the link : http://archive.cloudera.com/cloudera-labs/phoenix/parcels/latest/

Answer (score 1):

[New Apache Phoenix 4.5.2 Package from Cloudera Labs](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/11/new-apache-phoenix-4-5-2-package-from-cloudera-labs/)